# A rule represent ONLY Azure IPs for Azure firewall

Tags: azure, firewall

Can we create a firewall rule in azure to allow connections from azure data centre ONLY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this can't be done.

Fundamentally, Azure doesn't reside within a singe IP address range, nor does each Azure region. In fact, each region is broken into multiple address ranges which aren't necessarily concurrent. The ability to define a single firewall rule (which covers the entirety of Azure's infrastructure) would require some work in Azure to define, and maintain, a variable which holds all of these values.

It may be worth pointing out that Azure does already offer similar solutions for *Internet* and *VirtualNetwork*, which are applied in the [default NSG rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg#default-rules). As the majority of infrastructure within Azure, but outside of your virtual network, is essentially the *Internet*, setting such a variable for all Azure IPs would give a user the option to, potentially unknowingly, open up their resources to any kind of malicious activity.

Depending upon what exactly it is you are attempting to achieve, Azure does offer workarounds in the form of [Service Endpoints](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/virtual-network-service-endpoints-and-firewalls-for-azure-storage-now-generally-available/). This functionality has recently left the *preview* phase, and allows a user to create a security rule between certain [PaaS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-paas/) resources and your virtual network. Currently, this functionality is restricted to *Azure Storage*, *Azure SQL Database* and *Azure SQL Data Warehouse*.

An extremely sloppy way of implementing firewall rules for all Azure IP ranges would be to manually enter the address ranges from the region(s) you require, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653). However, doing this would be highly discouraged due to security flaws previously mentioned, plus these IP ranges are not entirely static, therefore it would be easy to get caught out if Microsoft was to edit certain address ranges.